# Migration JGraph to Graphx

Tags: migration, jgraphx, jgraph

We know all that JGraph is a very powerful graphic library and now we are in version 6 (JGraphx).
Me I have an application (by the way I am newbye in JGraph) coded in JGraph 5 and I want to migrate it to Graphx.

Is there any tut to know what is the main differences between these two versions?
That migration, is it easy to do (in general)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JGraph (the last version of which was version 5) and JGraphX (which was originally going to be called JGraph 6) are completely different code-bases. JGraphX was a complete rewrite from scratch, which is why we made the naming change to avoid the idea you could upgrade from 5 to 6.

So no, there is no migration route, you'd need to re-write your part of the application that interfaces with JGraph(X).

Comment: We left it for Netbeans Visual Library